# How to disable interactive mode in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

When using tkinter in the Python Shell, it prints out

```
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```

which means that one could edit tkinter windows in real time. However, the interactive mode seems to be keeping a mainloop running even if its window was destroyed, which in my case is blocking the script.

There has to be a way to disable interactive mode, something like `tk.set_interactive(False)`, but neither in the internet nor in the documentation I found a hint.

In case it is relevant, this is how my code looks like:

```
def select_file():
    root = tk.Tk()

    def do_stuff(file):
        ...
        file_picker.destroy()

    root.after(10, lambda: do_stuff(..))
    root.mainloop()
    return ...
```

Comment: Did you try `matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()`?

Comment: @acw1668 This does not work, but how can options in matplotlib affect tkinter?